# When was the Ottoman mosque within the Parthenon demolished?

Tags: ottoman-empire, greece

After the [Great Turkish War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Turkish_War) of 1683 - 1699, the Ottomans built a small mosque in the ruined Parthenon using salvaged materials from Parthenon itself. This was after it was catastrophically damaged by a gunpowder explosion in 1687.

Here are two depictions of the mosque inside the Parthenon and then one without it:

**Early 1830's**
[image]
Peytier - Mosque in the Parthenon

**1839:**

[image]
Engraving of the first photograph of the Parthenon. Daguerreotype photograph taken by Pierre-Gustave Joly de Lotbinière in October, 1839. Engraved by Frédéric Martens. Published in Excursions daguerriennes by Noël Paymal Lerebours in 1841.

**1848 -**  the Mosque now does not appear:

[image]
photo taken from [this forum](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?p=130388108)

So my question is, when was the Mosque inside the parthenon actually demolished? Do we have a date for it?

Also a bonus question, do we know if the original photo taken by Pierre-Gustave Joly de Lotbinière in October, 1839 still exists? or has that since been lost?

Comment: Here's a more detailed article regarding the Ottoman mosque inside the Greek Parthenon:
https://madainproject.com/parthenon_mosque

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There were actually two mosques built within [the Parthenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenon), [the first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenon#Islamic_mosque) was mostly destroyed when the explosion took place in 1687.  The second mosque, which you are referring to is discussed in *[The Parthenon: From Antiquity to the Present](https://books.google.com/books?id=gA81kINAI9cC&pg=PR8&dq=parthenon%20reconstruction&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhy-CkxLvRAhVmjVQKHeMhBXwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=mosque&f=false)*, by Jenifer Neils.  On page 324 it is stated that the small mosque had been damaged in sieges in 1821, 1826, and was finally

> ...removed in 1843 following the Greek War of Independence and the
>   beginning of modern archeological activity on the Acropolis.

This coincides with what is mentioned in wikipedi on [Independent Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenon#Independent_Greece):

> When independent Greece gained control of Athens in 1832, the visible
>   section of the minaret was demolished; only its base and spiral
>   staircase up to the level of the architrave remain intact.[103] Soon
>   *all the medieval and Ottoman buildings on the Acropolis were
>   destroyed*.

(emphasis mine)